# Mina SSHD enable KEX with SHA1 in version 2.6.0

Tags: scala, ssh, apache-mina

When using Mina SSHD (for SFTP) in version 2.6.0 the KEX for diffie-hellman SHA1 have been removed (as it should) but in my setup I need to be able to allow this for backward capability.

I can see when I try to connect to the server I get an Exception with: `Unable to negotiate key exchange for KEX algorithms (client: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256 / server: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1)` as expected when the server only accept old SHA1.

In the Mina code [BaseBuilder.java](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/sshd-2.6.0/sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/common/BaseBuilder.java) I can see that the old KEX has been removed from the default KEX: `DEFAULT_KEX_PREFERENCE`. I have tried to add in the two missing KEX in my application by overwriting the  KEX factories like this (using the same functions as Mina itself):

```
// Default client    
val internalSshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient()

// Set additional KEXs
val unsafeKexList: util.ArrayList[BuiltinDHFactories] = new util.ArrayList[BuiltinDHFactories](BaseBuilder.DEFAULT_KEX_PREFERENCE)
unsafeKexList.add(BuiltinDHFactories.dhg14)
unsafeKexList.add(BuiltinDHFactories.dhg1)
internalSshClient.setKeyExchangeFactories(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(true, unsafeKexList, ClientBuilder.DH2KEX))
```

And when i then iterates over the created ssh session KEX i get this:

```
sshClientSession.getKeyExchangeFactories.asScala.foreach(kex => {
  println(s"Client session KEX: ${kex.getName}")
})

// Client session KEX: ecdh-sha2-nistp521
// Client session KEX: ecdh-sha2-nistp384
// Client session KEX: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group17-sha512
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group15-sha512
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
// Client session KEX: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

But the connection still fails with the exception that my client don't provide any KEX supported by server. I can't find any additional documentation on this issue on Mina and I can't see what I could be missing.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution** simply add the following line of code after instantiating the sshd/sftp client

```
SshClient client = ...
```

Below should solve the problem.

```
client.setKeyExchangeFactories(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(
        false,
        BuiltinDHFactories.VALUES,
        ClientBuilder.DH2KEX
    ));

client.setSignatureFactories(new ArrayList<>(BuiltinSignatures.VALUES))
```

For putty support

https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/files-parsing.md

Simply add the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshd-common</artifactId>
    <version>...same version as the rest of the artifacts...</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
    <artifactId>sshd-putty</artifactId>
    <version>...same version as the rest of the artifacts...</version>
</dependency>
```

**Explanation** After comparing 2.5.1 to 2.7.0, seems that team of **Mina SSHD** forgot to add 3 Key KeyExchanges ^_^

default supported KeyExchange in v2.7.0

```
0 = {DHGClient$1@3636} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[ecdh-sha2-nistp521]"
1 = {DHGClient$1@3637} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[ecdh-sha2-nistp384]"
2 = {DHGClient$1@3638} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[ecdh-sha2-nistp256]"
3 = {DHGEXClient$1@3639} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256]"
4 = {DHGClient$1@3640} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]"
5 = {DHGClient$1@3641} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group17-sha512]"
6 = {DHGClient$1@3642} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group16-sha512]"
7 = {DHGClient$1@3643} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group15-sha512]"
8 = {DHGClient$1@3644} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group14-sha256]"
```

In v2.5.1 above items are supported including below 3 ones.

```
9 = {DHGEXClient$1@4216} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1]"
10 = {DHGClient$1@4222} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]"
11 = {DHGClient$1@4223} "NamedFactory<KeyExchange>[diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]"
```