# Spring Integration SFTP connection fails - Unable to negotiate key exchange for kex algorithms

Tags: java, spring-integration, sftp

I am using Spring Integration (Version: 6.1.2) to connect to an SFTP server. While creating an SFTPSession, I get this exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
....
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: Unable to negotiate key exchange for kex algorithms (

client: 
curve25519-sha256,
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,
curve448-sha512,
ecdh-sha2-nistp521,
ecdh-sha2-nistp384,
ecdh-sha2-nistp256,
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,
diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,
diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,
ext-info-c

server: 
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1)
```

Obviously, the server only supports the old algorithms. How do I add support for these algorithms on my SFTP session?

Here is my code -

```
DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
factory.setHost("ftp.sssss.com");
factory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(22));
factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
factory.setUser("user");
factory.setPassword("password");

SftpSession sftpSession = factory.getSession();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently those algorithms have been deprecated: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-1004.

This SO thread explains how to enable those old keys: [Mina SSHD enable KEX with SHA1 in version 2.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986656/mina-sshd-enable-kex-with-sha1-in-version-2-6-0).

The `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` supports an external `SshClient`:

```
/**
 * Instantiate based on the provided {@link SshClient}, e.g. some extension for HTTP/SOCKS.
 * @param sshClient the {@link SshClient} instance.
 * @param isSharedSession true if the session is to be shared.
 */
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory(SshClient sshClient, boolean isSharedSession) {
```

So, you need to do like this:

```
SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
client.setKeyExchangeFactories(NamedFactory.setUpTransformedFactories(
        false,
        BuiltinDHFactories.VALUES,
        ClientBuilder.DH2KEX
    ));
client.setSignatureFactories(new ArrayList<>(BuiltinSignatures.VALUES))
```

and inject that `client` into `DefaultSftpSessionFactory`.

Comment: Thank you ! Trying this and got this exception -

An `AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier` must be configured on the externally provided SshClient instance

Comment: Seems that was from the factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true). After removing that line, I am getting this error - A password must be configured on the externally provided SshClient instance - while setting the password on the factory. Looks like I ned more confirguration on the client. Reading up on that. Thank you !

Comment: Correct. When you provide an external client, everything has to be configured on it: our policy is not to mutate external objects from our components.